# Objective c: How to get final scroll Position of UITextView on Touch up?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have an application, where two iPads are connected via Bluetooth LE. One iPad is **the sender**  and the other one is **the receiver** (user input disabled).

My goal is, if the **sender** is scrolling in a 'UITextView', I want to send a command to the **receiver** to scroll his `UITextView` to the same position.

**Question 1**: How do I get the Y-Scroll-Position of the sender? 
(sth like: `[myTextView currentScrollPosition]` )

I use the `(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` to detect the end of scrolling. However, to get a better "synchronized" feeling..

**Question 2**: Is it possible to listen to the `TouchUp Event` from the User (that means: User ends scrolling, but UITextView still continues his "lazy scrolling to end") and get the  end scroll position at that moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

question 2:

a fast answer: use

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
```

(same UIScrollViewDelegate Protocol Reference as scrollViewDidEndDecelerating)

question 1:

i'm not sure i got the question point... scrollViewDidEndDecelerating is the right place to get y-scroll position... what else do you need?

Comment: question 1 was the `self.myTextView.contentOffset.y` statement. it returned null all the time. now everything work like expected (guess i made some mistakes). thanks a lot!